# why does Xcode code correction take a longer time since Xcode 7

Tags: xcode

When I installed Xcode 7 about a year ago I realized that the code correction was delayed for a number of seconds (longer than previous Xcode versions in my observation). At that time I was using an early 2011 MacBook Pro with 4GB Ram. I thought the issue was related to average spec laptop, but recently I upgraded to a 2015 MacBook Pro with 16GB Ram and the code correction still takes about the same time. I am currently using Xcode 8. Am I the only who has made this observation and what could cause it?